# Holomorphic function in doubly connected region

Tags: complex-analysis

This is exercise 2 from Lars Ahlfors,Chapter 5, section 1.3

"Let $V$ be a doubly connected region whose complement consists of
the components $E_1, E_2$. Prove that every analytic function $f(z)$ in $V$ can
be written in the form $f_1(z) + f_2(z)$ where $f_1(z)$ is analytic outside of $E_1$
and $f_2(z)$ is analytic outside of $E_2$."

My professor also claims that this result can be extended to regions whose complement consists of finite connected components but I really have no idea about how I can prove this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you understand the proof for doubly connected regions? Can you reproduce it here, so that we can suggest how to generalize it for multiply connected regions?

Comment: I don't know the proof about doubly connected regions. I think that if I knew it I could generalize it.